# Can flexbox CSS resize to aspect ratio?

Tags: css

I have a responsive column, which is then divided into 3 equal sub-columns.

I have an icon placeholder in each one with a width of 100%. Is there any way using CSS's flex to ensure that my height always equals what ever my computed width is?

I really want to avoid images and JavaScript if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods you could use. One is to set the height of the flexbox using `vw`. You could also use `calc` if needed. Of course if the page width becomes static on wider viewports or has a `max-width` set then you can use a media query to set the flexbox height in `px`, `em` etc.

The second method is to use padding on the flexbox child elements. Unlike margin, 100% top or bottom padding means 100% of the parent's width not height.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.flex div {
    flex: 1;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyOS4wMzE4MTMiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAyOS4wMzE4MTMiPgo8ZyB0cmFuc2Zvcm09Im1hdHJpeCgwLjAzMTI1LDAsMCwwLjAzMTI1LDAsLTAuOTY4MTg3NSkiPgo8cGF0aCBkPSJNIDEwMjQsNTkwLjQ0NCA1MTIsMTkzLjAxOCAwLDU5MC40NDYgMCw0MjguNDA4IDUxMiwzMC45ODIgMTAyNCw0MjguNDEgWiBNIDg5Niw1NzYgbCAwLDM4NCAtMjU2LDAgMCwtMjU2IC0yNTYsMCAwLDI1NiAtMjU2LDAgMCwtMzg0IDM4NCwtMjg4IHoiLz4KPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
.flex.vw {
    height: 16.67vw;
}
.flex.padding div {
    padding-top: 16.67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex vw">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="flex padding">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```